# Using table 'as' across a join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find all of the skills a every user doesn't have for a position.

I know this is incorrect, but I can't think of a way to make this work.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
select id, count(skillcode)
from person p, (
    select skillcode from requires_skill where poscode='1'
    minus
    select skillcode from hasskill where id=p.id)
group by p.id;
```

The part that isn't working is **id=p.id**.

I am using Oracle SQL.

Edit:
These are the sample tables

```
requires_skill
------------------
poscode | skillcode
-------------------
  1     |    2
  1     |    3
  1     |    4

hasskill
--------------------
id      | skillcode
--------------------
1       |    2
2       |    2
2       |    3
```

Expected output:

```
id    |    count(skillcode)
--------------------------
1     |     2
2     |     1
```

Comment: Show some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: Please create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if you want a perfect answer. Or, post all the create and insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **JOIN** the `person` and `hasskill` tables and use **NOT EXISTS** instead of **MINUS**.

Something like,

```
SELECT p.ID,
  COUNT(h.skillcode)
FROM person p
JOIN hasskill h
ON p.ID = h.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT skillcode FROM requires_skill WHERE poscode='1'
  )
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding your question about the **JOIN**, you need to use an **ALIAS** for the sub-query.

For example,

```
WITH DATA AS
  ( SELECT skillcode FROM requires_skill WHERE poscode='1'
  MINUS
  SELECT skillcode FROM hasskill h, person p WHERE h.ID=p.ID
  )
SELECT p.ID,
  COUNT(a.skillcode)
FROM person p
JOIN data A
ON a.skillcode = p.skillcode
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

Comment: This will not work, _select skillcode from requires_skill where poscode='1'_ will return rows, therefore the query will return nothing.

Comment: So you need to post the sample data as create and insert statements. Or, at least create a SQL Fiddle,

Comment: @carter Regarding your question about the JOIN, you need to use an ALIAS for the sub-query. see the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scalar subquery like this

```
select id, (select count(1) from requires_skill) - cnt from (select id, count(1) cnt from hasskill group by id);
```

It works as long as there is foreign key relation ship between requires_skill and hasskill.